# Maintaining sessions in mvc dynamic application

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

I am working on a web application of my own.Iam using Spring-mvc3 architecture n my application.I want to add authentication to my application.I thought of doing it by sessions but am not able to do so.I have created a login page and after login am able to authenticate and go to next page and get data that i have saved during session creation.Then after that when am navigating to another page my session data that i have saved is getting lost and when iam trying to get the session id am getting a new session id which is different from the one the got created at the time of authentication please check this and provide me the appropriate answer.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "checkLogin.action")
public String validateLogin(
        @ModelAttribute("loginDto") LoginDto loginDetails,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    boolean validUser;
    try {
        validUser = userDao.validateLogin(loginDetails);
        if (validUser) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            if (session.isNew()) {
                logger.debug("New Session is Created");
                System.out.println("Session id is" + session.getId());
            } else {
                logger.debug("Not a New Session");
                System.out.println("Session Id" + session.getId());
            }
            //session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1000);
            session.setAttribute("LoginData", loginDetails);
            session.setAttribute("loggedUser",true);

            return "home";
        }
        return "redirect:loginPage.action?message=Unable to Login invalid Id/Password";

    } catch (DaoException e) {
        logger.error("Problem in UserDao");
        return "redirect:loginPage.action?message=Unable to Login invalid Id/Password";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("problem validating User Login");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "redirect:loginPage.action?message=Unable to Login invalid Id/Password";
    }
}
```

this is how am setting data in my session and am able to retrieve that set attributes in view home to which on success it goes to, from home if i go to another view there am not able to get that data.

I wanted to know using anchor tag for navigating to another page clears the session data??????

Comment: - Are cookies allowed on your pages? - Do you have multiple servers where this application is deployed?

Comment: In such a scenario would you not consider integrating Spring Security? It is more or less out of the box for the spring mvc stuff anyway

Comment: no am working on only one tomcat server ya yes cookies are allowed #TJ

Comment: #Niels its not about the security am concerned about am concerned about the maintaining of session data and session

Comment: The container is supposed to handle maintaining the session for you.  Are you forwarding off to a different server?  Or somehow invalidating the session, either in the client or somewhere in the code?  Also, why not use something like Spring Security?  Just curious.

Comment: am not invalidating session any where.no the server is same